# Jenkins daily downstream job

Tags: jenkins, nexus, promoted-builds

In our continuous integration implementation we build a new WAR/Jar file every few minutes and deploy this to a Nexus Snapshot repository as bleeding edge candidate. this is working satisfactory.

We also run a lot of automated QA (findbugs, junit, etc) as downstream jobs, these jobs are much longer running and sometimes regress.
Only when there is no regression/QA-failure we want to consider the artifact as a Release.

However using a downstream job on the original build (which produced a snapshot and archived the artifact in jenkins) We end up with way to many releases.

So what we are looking for is some way to have daily job as a 'upstream' job so we can use promoted-builds to make a release daily.

The diagram below outlines what we are trying to do

```
                 Create_snapshot
                       |
                --+----+------+--
                  |           |
          quick-regression    |      
                  |           |
 --+--------+-----+---+--     |
   |        |         |       |
Findbugs Integration Junit    |
   |       test      tests   Daily-trigger
   |        |         |       |
   |        |         |       |
   |        |         |       |
   |        |         |       |
---+--------+----+----+-------+--
                 |
          Deploy-as-release
```

Comment: is this diagram generated ?

Comment: nope (copied from other question with similar problem and adjusted :) )

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [Join plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) to trigger your 3 test jobs after the quick-regression job?

Because with this plugin, you can trigger your 3 test jobs and if they are successful, then you can trigger your deploy-as-release job.

If you want to build only one release per day, you can maybe use the [Conditional BuildStep plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) (on the deploy-as-release job) to limit the number of releases.

Will this solution work for you?

Comment: I'm using the promoted builds plugin, but the conditional buildstep plugin sound exactly like what i was looking for :)

Comment: Cool, please keep inform on how you set up this plugin to solve your issue ;)